# .next() element with a specific attribute( id) in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").click(function(){
    var level= $(this).attr('id');
    alert(level);
      var ss= $(level).next().attr('id');
      alert(ss);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="btn" id="1"src="img_pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213"><br>
<img class="btn" id="2"src="img_pulpitrock.jpg" alt="Pulpit Rock" width="284" height="213"><br>
```

I always want to get the next element id.  why not defined? level is dynamic.

```
var level //global
         $(".button").click(function () {
               level = $(this).attr("id");
                alert(level);//working
            });
   var ss= $(level).next().attr('id');
      alert(ss);//undefined
```

Comment: `attr()`, not `atrr()`. Even then you should be using `prop()` instead.

Comment: include html mark up as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that your level variable is defined only if user click on a .button.

So when you define ss, level is not defined yet. Remember that JavaScript is mostly asynchronous.

So you must do this :

```
var level //global
     $(".button").click(function () {
           level = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(level);//working
            var ss= $('#' + level).next().attr('id');
            alert(ss);//defined
        });
```

Didn't saw your edit with adding the HTML.

Have fixed my code proposal. But i really suggest to you to not use number as an id. And here, if you click on the second, and last, .btn, there is no next. SO it will crash. And not use "ss" as a name of variable. Because it doesn't mean nothing. With actual code minification and code autocomplete in IDEs, no more need of small variables names.

Comment: Yes thanks. I changed the question. do you look again?

Comment: Edited and fixed.

Comment: Thanks. But not working.  ss is not defined yet

Comment: didn't saw your html. Have added some fix in my answer